# Extract object from object array

Tags: javascript

I need to split an object array into two variables. The first variable (`main`) should get the object with a `title`.
The second one (`content`) should get all other objects.

*Sample data*

```
[
  { _id: '1', title: 'Main' },
  { _id: '2', foo: 'bar' },
  { _id: '2', foo: 'bar' }
]
```

I did it with`find()`/`filter()` commands, but is it really necessary to find twice?

```
const main = data.find(doc => doc.title)
const content = data.filter(doc => !doc.title)
```

Is it possible to extract the main object instead of finding it?

Comment: What if we have two entries with 'title'?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by _“extract the main object instead of finding it”_. How would “extracting” look like if it’s not just “finding”? Other than that, your current solution already seems quite elegant. I’m not sure how it could be improved significantly.

Comment: Assuming you actually mean `data.filter` on the second line, I don't think there is anything wrong with it. Unless your array is huge there won't be any performance difference. And your current solution is much more readable than some other approaches.

Comment: Trivial with lodash `let {false: docs, true: [main]} = _.groupBy(ary, x => !!x.title)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a single loop approach and an object for same named arrays with a check if the property exist with [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).

```js
var data = [{ _id: '1', title: 'Main' }, { _id: '2', foo: 'bar' }, { _id: '2', foo: 'bar' }],
     main = [],
     content = [],
     temp = { main, content };

data.forEach(doc => temp['title' in doc ? 'main' : 'content'].push(doc));

console.log(main);
console.log(content);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With just one object with title, you could assign the object directly and collec the other objects in an array.

```js
var data = [{ _id: '1', title: 'Main' }, { _id: '2', foo: 'bar' }, { _id: '2', foo: 'bar' }],
     main,
     content = [];

data.forEach(doc => 'title' in doc
    ? main = doc
    : content.push(doc)
);

console.log(main);
console.log(content);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Would it be possible to have `main` as an object - as it is aways only one object?

Comment: @user3142695, yes it is possible, take example two.

Answer (score 0):

```
const content = data.find(doc => !doc.title)
```

This doesn't work, because `find` returns one object only (the first found), not all the objects that don't match the condition. You'll have to use a filter for that

```
const content = data.filter(doc => !doc.title)
```

So yes, you'll have to iterate twice, one time to find the matching object, and a second time to build an array excluding the matching object.

Answer (score 0):

```
var docs = [
  { _id: '1', title: 'Main' },
  { _id: '2', foo: 'bar' },
  { _id: '2', foo: 'bar' }
];

var doc = [],main = [];

for(_doc in docs){
    if(typeof docs[_doc].title != 'undefined') {
        doc.push(docs[_doc]);
        continue;
  }

  main.push(docs[_doc]);
}
```

Working fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/andreitodorut/fcLkata6/

Answer (score 0):

I would do this a bit differently.  The notion of partitioning a list by a predicate is worth extracting.  So I might do this:

```js
const docs = [{_id: '1', title: 'Main'},{_id: '2', foo: 'bar'},{_id: '2', foo: 'bar'}]

const partition = pred => data => data.reduce(
  ([matches, mismatches], item) => pred(item) 
     ? [matches.concat(item), mismatches]
     : [matches, mismatches.concat(item)],
  [[], []]
)

const withTitle = partition(doc => 'title' in doc)

console.log(withTitle(docs))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Of course it's quite possible that `withTitle` should be inlined, if it's not being reused.  It's also possible that the currying I put in, my usual default, is not necessary for you, and it should read `(pred, data) => data.reduce(...)`